# Unable to clear value for struts property

Tags: javascript, struts-1

Unable to clear the struts property value.Script error - "Cannot set value for style "null"

```
 <html:form name="form1">
 <html:password property="PASSWORD" styleId="Password"/>
 </html:form>
```

My javascript code as follows

```
function clearValue(){
document.getElementById('Password').value="";
}
```

Comment: After rendering it on web, please check id property is there for password field or not.

Comment: That error doesn't have to do with that line of code, that error is saying you are trying to do something with style.

Answer (score 0):

document.forms[0].password.value="";

or something like you need to do

```
tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
switch(tags[i].type) {
    case 'password':
    case 'text':
        tags[i].value = '';
        break;
    case 'checkbox':
    case 'radio':
        tags[i].checked = false;
        break;
  }
 }

 tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  if(tags[i].type == 'select-one') {
     tags[i].selectedIndex = 0;
 }
else {
    for(j = 0; j < tags[i].options.length; j++) {
        tags[i].options[j].selected = false;
    }
}
   }

tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
     tags[i].value = '';
}
```

Then I just call this function with the button and it clears everything out. Thanks for your help though.